# JavaScript Assignment for class

Tags: javascript, html

My teacher is having me create a page that needs to take in your outstanding balance, for a credit card, and have what you need to pay this month based on a couple of questions on the page. Ive been able to get the look right and i think i have most of the java correct but when i hit the button to have everything go thought the function it wont bring back an answer. If anyone could help me figure out what im doing wrong for future reference that would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
payDue = 0;
questions = {};
 var form = document.getElementsByName('questions')[0];
    for(var i=0,len=form.length;i<len;i++) {
        questions[form[i].name] = form[i];
    }

function calcPay(form){
    balance= questions.bal.value;
    if (questions.ontime.checked == true){
        if (questions.mini.checked == true){
            payDue=bal/10;
        }
        else if(questions.spec.checked == true){
            payDue=questions.speca.value ;
        }
        else if(questions.due.checked == true){
            payDue=balance ;
        }
    }
    else if (questions.late.checked == true){
        if(questions.mini.checked == true){
        payDue=bal/10 + 10;
        }
        else if(questions.spec.checked == true){
            payDue=questions.speca.value +10;
        }
        else if(questions.due.checked == true){
            payDue=balance +10;
        }
    }
return(payDue);
}
</script>
<title>Recreation</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="questions">
<h1>Calculate Payment</h1>
<p>Enter name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>Enter credit card number: <input type="text" name="ccn"></p>
<p>Enter balance: <input type="text" name="bal"></p>
<p>Enter Status:</p>
   <input type="radio" name="ontime">Ontime<br />
    <input type="radio" name="late">Late<br />
    <p>Enter payment plan:</p>
   <input type="radio" name="mini">Minimum 10%<br />
    <input type="radio" name="spec">Specified Amount<br />
    <input type="radio" name="due">Amount Due<br />
    <p>Specified Amount: <input type="text" name="speca"></p>

<p><input type="button" name="toClick" value="Calculate Your Pay"
           onclick="questions.whatsDue.value = calcPay(questions)"></p>

<p><i><b>Your pay is: <input type="text" name="whatsDue"></b></i></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI This is NOT Java. Java is very different from Javascript

Comment: Also, information on errors given would be very helpful. Have you created the variable `bal` anywhere?

Comment: You should use the Developer's console to debug your 'JavaScript' application. The way you are doing it, the form will never get instantiated in your code

Comment: @progrAmmar im using dream weaver and im not sure what a developer's console is

Comment: @Howzieky how do i see errors that happen? I use dream weaver and i open the page in google chrome to test it.

Comment: @MichaelCorreia Developer console is in the browser where you can debug your page. The browser that you open your page in, hit F12 key and the developer console will come it (it is in all modern browsers) there you can see the errors in the console

Comment: @progrAmmar Thank you that helped me fix it, i just had to remove the var form and change fucntion calcPay(form) to function calcPay(questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
payDue = 0;
questions = {};
 var form = document.getElementsByName('questions')[0];
for(var i=0,len=form.length;i<len;i++) {
    questions[form[i].name] = form[i];
}

function calcPay(form){
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
payDue = 0;
    function calcPay(questions){
```